# How to avoid private property null check to do lazy loading?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class with like 20 fields which get populated from SQL database on load. Currently I am calling load data method right after the constructor, which calls SQL proc and populate all the required fields. At times, I may not access the these 20 fields at all, I am adding additional cost of SQL call even though it was not required. So I changed all the properties to have an associated private property and when the program calls the public property, first I check the private property and if it is null that means we need to load data from sql so I call the load method. It works great, but when I see the code, there is a repeated pattern of null check and load the sql query. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{
   get {
      if (_name == null)
         LoadData(); //this popultes not just but all the properties
      return _name;
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems you made a single database call to 20 calls, do you think that is effective even on an average you access say only 6 - 8 values

Comment: @V4Vendetta No, he is just implementing the lazy load pattern. His comment says that he loads all properties when ANY property is called for the first time. The check will then be false on subsequent calls and only return the in memory values

Comment: Hey you can also check once with Constructor and bind data.

Comment: @SanjayGoswami That will defeat the purpose of the lazy load pattern. Please see the wikipedia article that I posted

Comment: @JustinPihony What happens in this case is at any point of time (even with the checks as in your answer) there is going to be a call made, so why confuse someone who looks at it 2 months down the line and be puzzled as why these calls show up in all those properties

Comment: @V4Vendetta Because this pattern can really save you on memory, and the code is not really complicated to understand. You could make your variable name more explicit if you want...bool isFullyConstructed or bool hasLazyLoadBeenCompleted

Comment: @JustinPihony : What is issue if we bind Constructor..? I feel its good.

Comment: @SanjayGoswami Because, the point of the lazy load pattern is saying that you can construct the object, but the data bindings will not occur unless they are actually needed. So, if you bind on construction, then the necessary values are already loaded, so you lose all of the benefits of lazy load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, this is right. [Here is the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). The overhead of the null check will be very minimal compared to unnecessary database calls. Now, if the users of the program actually use the values 99% of the time, then I would say this pattern is not needed.

Just one note of caution: If any of your values could possibly be null, then you will make unnecessary database calls. It might be better to do something like this (which will be an even quicker check since it is just a bit check):

```
//Constructor default to not loaded
bool isLoaded = false;

private string _name;
public string Name 
{
   get {
      if (!isLoaded)
         LoadData(); //this popultes not just but all the properties
      return _name;
   }
}   

private LoadData()
{
    //Load Data
    isLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, could you please elaborate as to why you downvoted (if there is an off chance that you return and see this :p)

Comment: I had similar implementation then I thought, it might be an anti pattern. I am glad it is good solution. I will go with this one.

Comment: Nope, not an anti-pattern. However, as I (and others) mentioned. Make sure that even this minimal overhead is worth it. If the users are almost always hitting the load, then there is no real point to it. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Btw C# now has default lazy-loaders implementation. Why not to use it, instead of providing isSomethingLoaded flags? :)

```
public class Bar
{
    private Lazy<string> _name = new Lazy<string>(() => LoadString());

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name.Value; }
    }
}
```

In case of non-static LoadString method, lazy-loader should be initialized in constructor;

Comment: WOW did not know Lazy exists in C#, does it do null check and load? I will look up on it. If it is available, this is something I should use instead of us using another flag to check for loading data.

Comment: Yes, it exists since .Net 4. Yes, it do null check and loads value via provided delegate. Good news - you can use it not only with reference types, but with value types also.

Comment: hi then whats the difference bw singleton design pattern and lazy? i think both seem same.

Comment: Nope. Singleton's purpose is to guarantee that only one instance of object will exist in the system. You can create that instance immediately (e.g. during instance field initialization), or during first call to instance (lazy). Lazy loading just postpones instance initialization until it needed, but you can have many instances of lazy-loaded objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could change it to:

```
if (!initialized)
    LoadData();
```

And in your LoadData set initialized to true, but that really doesn't change the semantics of it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to extract if into separate method so each property contains just one additional call:

```
void EnsureData()
{
      if (!dataLoaded) 
         LoadData(); //this populates all the properties 
}

public string Name {
   get { 
      EnsureData();
      return _name; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider your application structure. Why would you even instantiate the class if you are not going to be using the properties? I believe it's actually cleaner for you to call the SQL after your constructor code but only create the objects of your class if you are going to be using it. The other more flexible solution is making the LoadData public and calling it as needed from the object instance as needed.

Comment: Without knowing the full structure of the OP's program, I dont know that you can make a blanket statement to not use the lazy load pattern. Most ORM's (including EF and nHibernate) use lazy loading to cut down on the stress to the database. It all depends on how the objects are being used.

Comment: I don't believe that I have told him not to use the lazy loading pattern. I simply told him to call the load as needed but but then again I have only used lazy loading with the EF repository pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your answer I guess. Also, FYI I do not get a notice of your message if you do not tag me. I just happened to check back on this one

Comment: @JustinPihony - Yeah I did not get a response notification either. Did you get one now?

Comment: Yes, you should have though, as the OP and the question asnwerer should get it by default. The rest need tagged. BTW, this is off topic, so I am going to delete at noon est just to give you time to see this :)

Answer (score 0):

I am in the learning process of design patterns. i have one suggestion if you load data only once you can try with singleton design pattern.

```
public class Singleton123
{
    private static readonly string _property1 = ClassLoadData.LoadData();

    public static string MyProperty1
    {
        get
        {
            return _property1;
        }
    }

}

public class ClassLoadData
{
    public static string LoadData()
    {
        // any logic to load data
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Call property as below

```
Singleton123 obj = new Singleton123();
        string stra = Singleton123.MyProperty1;
        string strb = Singleton123.MyProperty1;
```

this property will be loaded only once.